# Glassfish Keystore Error after adding MySQL Connector

Tags: mysql, glassfish

Working on a school project and attempting to set up a JSF with Glassfish. Went through the motions of installing Glassfish, enabling it in Netbeans, and then installing the proper MySQL Driver from MySQL, copying it into the domains\domain1\lib folder after encountering the classPath error when attempting to run my program. After doing so I encounter a new error:

Ping Connection Pool failed for MySQL. The connection could not be allocated: Cannot open file:C:\Users(myusernamehere)\Documents\NetBeansProjects\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect] Please check the server.log for more details.

My JDK is updated appropriately:

c:>java -version
java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)

I've established the connection through Netbeans to MySQL without issue, and confirmed both the user name and password are operational in a previous program (One I'm currently converting to this JSF app for my project). I'm at a loss for what's causing the error.

Edit: The errors indicate multiple different sources for the error that feed the same message. "Severe: RAR5110 : Error creating managed Connection with user and password : {0} java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot open file:C:\Users(myusernamehere)\Documents\NetBeansProjects\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]" I've tried to switch to Payara instead of Glassfish, but when trying to establish a datasource connection it gives me a classpath error, despite having the updated J/Driver in the lib folder.

Comment: *"Please check the server.log for more details."* So did you? And what did it say?

Comment: Don't post clarifying information as a comment. Edit the question to add it there. Delete the comment.

Answer (score 36):

add useSSL = false in the additional properties

Example URL:

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/practicas?useTimeZone=true&serverTimezone=UTC&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false`

Comment: Worked for me too! Thanks.

Comment: Where? How? Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

[image]

or you can put `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Peoples?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false`
on URL pr.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem, changed the server to Apache, running fine now.
The reason I found is I was using Glassfish 4.2.1, and MYSQL 8.0 (Which now has caching_sha2_password) which is not compatible with each other.
Either Update your Glassfish version or move to apache