# Setting classpath in NetBeans

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans, classpath

I'm having an issue with NetBeans 8.2: when connecting to a database through a Java class a SQLException is raised and it tells me that the driver is missing. The thing is that:

1. The connection is fine when established via the option under the Services tab:

   [image: Services tab]
2. I already provided the IDE the connector by going "right-click on project" > properties > libraries, as shown in my Libraries directory in the Project tab:

   [image: Compile tab]

I tried to write, compile and run with the -cp option two programs to replicate the behaviour of the same programs I wrote for my project and everything works fine. Here's the code:

This program connects to the database, and returns the connection:

```
  public Connection connectToDB(String username, String password, String url){
    System.out.println("connecting...");
    try{
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
      System.out.println("connection succeded!");
      return conn;
    }catch(SQLException e){
      System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

This program simply tests the connection:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
    String username = "usr";
    String password = "password";
    ConnectToDB c = new ConnectToDB();
    Connection conn = c.connectToDB(username, password, url);
}
```

Here's the full stack trace for my project. Please note, in the project I connect to the database in the servlet for logging by instantiating the class ConnectToDB and calling the method connectToDB, in the same exact way I've shown above. The data I should retrieve goes into a factory for users and whatnot, and that's why it shows in the stacktrace.

```
Informazioni:   Loading application [WebProgrammingProject] at [/WebProgrammingProject]
Informazioni:   WebProgrammingProject was successfully deployed in 1.455 milliseconds.
Informazioni:   connecting to database...
Informazioni:   connection failed!
Informazioni:   java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/usr?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
Avvertenza:   StandardWrapperValve[Login]: Servlet.service() for servlet Login threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at model.UtenteFactory.getUsers(UtenteFactory.java:33)
    at control.Login.processRequest(Login.java:38)
    at control.Login.doGet(Login.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

EDIT: FYI, I tried to reinstall the whole lot in my current machine and hard formatting my hard drive but it didn't work. I reinstalled Win10, jdk 8, mysql 8.0.17 and NetBeans 8.2. I also tried to run my WebApp in another two machines (both of them Win10 and same versions of the same programs) but it didn't work either.

EDIT: apparently my problem needs some more explanation of the project structure.

Basically, I have to do a full website that simulates a peer-review journal that contains users (authors and organizers that give authors articles to review), articles and evaluations.

The app itself needs to be initialized as a Java Web > Web Application because my professor uses some kind of custom automated tool to grade my project, so I'm stuck with that.

The data from the database has to be retrieved through three Java factories: one factory for users, one factory for articles and one factory for the evaluations. The factories take the data from the database and their methods (such as get user by id, get article by date and so on) return the retrieved data to the various servlets that pass it on the jsps.

The connection to the database (we use MySQL) is performed by an external java class that connects and returns to the factories that request it a Connection type object.

Finally, the web app relies on Gliassfish 4.1.1

UPDATE

I managed to find another version of this project with another program I wrote for establishing a connection, and for a bit it worked fine. Too bad now it gives me a SQLNonTransientConnectionException exception.

Here's the code that temporarily worked:

```
public class DBConnection {
    private static DBConnection singleton;

    private DBConnection(){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
        }
    }

    public static DBConnection getInstance(){
        if(singleton == null)
        {
            singleton = new DBConnection();
        }
        return singleton;
    }

    public Connection getConnection(){
        Connection conn = null;
        String db = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
        String username = "usr";
        String password = "password";
        try{
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db, username, password);
            System.out.println("connection established");
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }

        return conn;
    }
}
```

And here's the stacktrace:

```
Grave:   Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
    Informazioni:   java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    Avvertenza:   StandardWrapperValve[Login]: Servlet.service() for servlet Login threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at model.UtenteFactory.getUsers(UtenteFactory.java:28)
        at model.UtenteFactory.getUserByEmailAndPassword(UtenteFactory.java:55)
        at controller.Login.processRequest(Login.java:41)
        at controller.Login.doGet(Login.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I'm seriously temped to give up on this: nothing is the way it should be and nothing behaves predictibly. Why it worked for some time and now it doesn't? I'm puzzled

Comment: a stackoverflow search [classpath NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=classpath+NetBeans) didnt help you out?

Comment: Sadly, no, because everybody solved their problem by going to project, libraries, compile tab and add jar file

Comment: Please provide the full exception stacktrace, the code as shown will not produce an error that the driver is missing, which means you are paraphrasing things, which can hide the problem.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sure thing. Just did it

Comment: [1] What is the exact name of the driver you believe you are using in your application? [2] What is the exact version of MySQL?

Comment: @skomisa [1]I tried two different drivers: the mysql-connector-java-8.0.16 and the mysql-connector-java-8.0.17, but none of them worked. I didn't change their names and they are in my desktop. [2] I'm using MySQL 8.0.17. But I doubt these factors matter, because when compiling and running the programs which code I posted originally everything works fine

Comment: Do you have the full error for that `SQLNonTransientConnectionException`? The question [Error trying to perform CRUD from JAVA webApp to MySQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57863113/2985643), and my comment for that question, might be relevant for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies with your configuration on the **Compile** tab. Try this simpler approach:

1. **{Project properties} > Libraries > Compile**, then remove the existing entries that are shown in the **Compile** tab on your screen shot.
2. **{Project properties} > Libraries > Compile > Add JAR/Folder**, then navigate to an instance of **mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar**. Click **Open** which will create a new entry on the **Compile** tab, and copy the Connector/J driver to your project's **lib** directory. In my case the **Compile** tab looked like this:

   [image: ConnectorJ driver]
3. Clean and build the project. This should create an entry in **META-INF/MANIFEST.MF** within your jar file that looks like this: `Class-Path: lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar`

Run the application and the driver will be found in your project's **lib** directory. I just verified that works for me on NB 8.2 when making a JDBC connection to MySQL in a simple Java application. It also works when running from the command line, if you submit the command shown in the **Output** window when doing a **Build**. In my case that command looked like this:

> To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
>
> **java -jar "D:\NB82\JdbcSelectTest\dist\JdbcSelectTest.jar"**

However, if you want to run your jar file from some arbitrary location - for example, on another machine - you will need to ensure that **mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar** remains on your classpath using the `-cp` option.

Comment: Ok, I deleted the previous entry and now my compile tab looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/zyUt8ge). NetBeans managed automatically the copy of the connector and my lib directory (assuming you're referring to [this](https://imgur.com/a/LxyNib3) lib directory: I don't have one in my project folder). Sadly cleaning and building didn't update the manifest.mf: it still doesn't show the entry you mentioned, as you can see [here](https://imgur.com/a/96UN04F). Also, my Output window probably looks different than yours. [Here it is](https://imgur.com/kkRVPbe)

Comment: @mootasa OK, clearly your project is not a simple Java Ant  application since the **Categories** of your project's properties are very different to those shown in my screen shot. Can you update your question with more details of the actual project with the problem, so that others can try to reproduce it? That said, you should still be able to create a trivial Java project (**File > New Project... > Java > Java Application**) that connects to MySQL using the approach in my answer. Does that work? But at least the addition of the driver to your project's **lib** directory looks good.

Comment: OK, I updated my original post. Hope I provided enough info. Also, I tried to create another project by going new project > java > java application and everything works fine: I can retrieve and insert data into my database