# Why is my java executable jar not connecting to the database?

Tags: java, mysql, jar, executable, executable-jar

I have written a java program that executes fine in the IDE, and makes a mysql connection. But when I right click the project, clean and build and then double click the jar file in the source folder. The program opens fine, but everything related to the database doesn't show..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, used the cli now, this is the error message: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kassaschema

Comment: You forgot to include the JDBC driver (jar file) in the executable jar, or in the classpath. Add it to one of them and it should run.

Comment: Sounds like a CLASSPATH issue, which is the cause of at least 90% of all problems in Java.

Comment: I'm using netbeans 11, and maven project, how exactly do I add it? Been looking for it but I don't really understand it..

Comment: Here's an example of a similar case of adding the mysql connector to the classpath in NetBeans: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57886755/setting-classpath-in-netbeans