# Web Project not connecting to MySQL

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am kinda new to coding and was trying to make a simple dynamic web application and link it to a MySQL database. But, when I try to run the application, it always fails to connect. Could anyone suggest what I am doing wrong ?
I am using Netbeans 12.1 with JDK 11 and GlassFish Server 5.1.0.
Thanks in advance

```
//First page with button
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
        <<form action="Trial.jsp">
            <input type="submit" value="Go">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
//Second page with SQL code
<%-- 
    Document   : Trial
    Created on : Sep 20, 2020, 12:15:38 PM
    Author     : Theboss12k
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
        <%
        Connection con;
        ResultSet rs;
        Statement st;
        
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","Pass");
            st=con.createStatement();
            out.println("Connection done");
            
        }
        catch(Exception ae){
            out.println("Connection failed");
        }
           

            
            
            
            %>
    </body>
</html>
```

The output is always "Connection Failed"

Comment: Check your server logs .Also you can use `ae.printStackTrace();` to see what actual error  is inside catch block. .

Comment: Thanks Swathi for the quick reply. I did as you had told and ran the Web Application again, but this time, there was no output for the particular block for which I had used `ae.printStackTrace()` in the catch part. I looked at the server log as you had suggested and it had given an output telling me that "java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot open file:C:\Users\Theboss12k\Downloads\glassfish-5.1.0\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect". Is there any way that I can fix this ?

Comment: Also, do I need to add the MySQL database to my glassfish server in order for it to run, or will it run from within the application itself ? Thanks in advance

Comment: It will run within application itself . Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51586401/glassfish-keystore-error-after-adding-mysql-connector) post will help you to solve above error .

Comment: Thanks @Swati for your help. I will try it out and let you know !!

Comment: @Swati I took a look at the post and it told me to add `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/practicas?useTimeZone=true&serverTimezone=UTC&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false` in additional properties. I couldnt find the additional properties field anywhere in Netbeans, so do I have to add the database to my GlassFish server ?

Comment: No add that `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"..` in your jsp code

Comment: @Swati Thank you sooo much for helping me out. I had been stuck on this for so long and couldnt find a solution, until I had asked here !! It worked properly now !!

Comment: Not too smart of an idea to reveal your database's password :/

Comment: Sorry for the really late reply, I had a slew of exams coming up. Thanks for the heads up, I forgot that my password was exposed ! But, I dont have any personal information over there (hopefully) so I guess it's fine xD